# Clean way to return an array from X.times in Ruby

Tags: ruby, code-cleanup

I often want to perform an action on an array X times then return a result other than that number. The code I usually write is the following:

```
  def other_participants
    output =[]
    NUMBER_COMPARED.times do
      output << Participant.new(all_friends.shuffle.pop, self)
    end
    output
  end
```

Is there a cleaner way to do this?

Comment: I swear this isn't for reputation, but I really think you accepted the wrong answer.  Collect is really EXACTLY the right one to use.  Even if you make another answer an accept that one, I really think you should accept a map/collect answer for when someone else comes by and looks at this question.

Comment: I thought the same thing myself after experimenting so I switched

Answer (score 31, accepted):

sounds like you could use map/collect (they are synonyms on Enumerable).  it returns an array with the contents being the return of each iteration through the map/collect.

```
def other_participants
  NUMBER_COMPARED.times.collect do
    Participant.new(all_friends.shuffle.pop, self)
  end
end
```

You don't need another variable or an explicit return statement.

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-collect

Answer (score 6):

You could use `each_with_object`:

```
def other_participants
  NUMBER_COMPARED.times.each_with_object([]) do |i, output|
    output << Participant.new(all_friends.shuffle.pop, self)
  end
end
```

From the [fine manual](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object):

> **each_with_object(obj) {|(*args), memo_obj| ... } → obj**
>   **each_with_object(obj) → an_enumerator**
>
> Iterates the given block for each element with an arbitrary object given, and returns the initially given object.
>   If no block is given, returns an enumerator.

Comment: Imperative programmer! Rot in silicon hell!

Comment: @Andrew: Get off my lawn kid!

Answer (score 2):

I thing something like this is best

```
def other_participants
  shuffled_friends = all_friends.shuffle
  Array.new(NUMBER_COMPARED) { Participant.new(shuffled_friends.pop, self) }
end
```